# Load large shapefile just at data frame current view

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile

Is there a way to just load a large shapefile at just my current data frame view or select and export a shapefile by a polygon without loading it?

I have a country's pipelines but I want just to select and export a small village's pipes and prevent time-consuming loading of that large file.

Comment: You could certainly use a Python Toolbox script to add a layer with Definition Query that only renders the features you desire (provided an attribute reflects that need)

Comment: Set environment extent to your polygon and use copy features tool on a large dataset. Better than Clip, because complete shape will be extracted.